# Android Studio 0.8 Beta Screen Capture / Video Capture broken

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

I upgraded Android Studio from 0.6.2 to 0.8 beta last night, with no issues.

Unfortunately, I just tried to grab a video capture from Glass (I've been sending regular progress updates in this way) to find it doesn't work any more. Pressing record skips the actual recording process and jumps straight to the save dialogue, saving a video file with no content.

The screen capture button shows an error:

```
Unexpected error while obtaining screenshot: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @NotNull method com/android/tools/idea/ddms/screenshot/DeviceArtDescriptor.getArtDescriptor must not return null
```

Any ideas what might be causing this or how to fix it?

Comment: it would be probably better if you fill up a bugreport

Comment: Fair point but I thought I'd see if anyone else had seen the issue and potentially fixed it.

Comment: I have the same problem. Temporary solution is to use android-studion/sdk/tools/ddms.bat

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It is a known issue, and has been fixed for 0.8.2; however, there is a work-around to fix it for this version.

**Solution**

> If anyone needs a workaround: edit the following file in your Android
>   Studio distribution:
>   **plugins/android/lib/device-art-resources/device-art.xml**
>
> On line 33, insert `<!--` and on line 43 insert `-->`
>
> In other words, comment out the two tv device definitions. They don't
>   supply a portrait orientation, which is what is causing the crash in
>   the screenshot code (when it searches for device art to surround the
>   device with).
>
> If you do this, note that you may get conflicts in a future update, so
>   please copy the original file somewhere and restore it before updating
>   to 0.8.2.

Posted by Tnor, on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72580.

Answer (score -3):

It turns out this was entirely my own fault - I was running an emulator I'd forgotten about which meant adb didn't know which device I wanted to record.

The trick is to make sure only one device is connected to adb, or set a default.

Comment: This still happens even with only one device connected (and no emulators running).  Problem persists after restarting Android Studio as well.

Comment: Yes, I just switched between the emulator and a real device, shut down the emulator, and am getting this error.

Comment: Same problem here. So it's an Android Studio bug?

Comment: I posted a link to the bug tracker in another answer but I guess someone deleted it. Here is the issue in the bug tracker: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=72580 Word is it will be fixed in the next update.